# Lucene doesn't search text having '_'

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lucene search and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520479/lucene-search-and-underscores)

I am using Lucene full text search for searching in my application.

But for example, if I search for 'Turbo_Boost' it returns 0 results.

For other text it works fine.

Any Idea?

Comment: I have been researching this online and have already seen a few sets of charectors that are not accepted in the searches. This one i have not seen yet, but if i find this i will post as answer.

Comment: Perhaps it considers `_` as a word separator so `Turbo` and `Boost` are two independent words in your text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520479/lucene-search-and-underscores

Comment: You should post your indexing code and the code you use to search.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the [`StandardTokenizer`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html), it will split on the underscore character.

You can get around this by [providing your own `Tokenizer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325729/lucene-net-underscores-causing-token-split/4326405#4326405) which will keep the underscore in the [`Token`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Token.html) that's returned (either through a combination of `Filter` instances or `TokenFilter` instances).

Comment: I don't think that the problem is related with StandardAnalyzer. Since it will split the tokens while both indexing & searching, you should be able to find the result.(Turbo_Boost is converted to a PhraseQuery like "turbo boost" which is OK)

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb with Lucene is to tokenize your search queries using the same Tokenizer/Analyzer you used to index the data.

see http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Why_is_it_important_to_use_the_same_analyzer_type_during_indexing_and_search.3F

Comment: This link is dead, please update or delete

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a few reasons why your query would fail:

First, and probably the least likely, considering other text searches fine, you didn't set the document's field to be analyzed.  It won't be tokenized, so you can only search against the exact value of the whole field.  Again, this one is probably not your issue.

The second (related to the third), and fairly likely, would depend on how you're executing the search.  If you are not using the `QueryParser` (which analyzes your text the same way you index it if constructed properly) and instead say you are using a `TermQuery` like:

```
var tq = new TermQuery("Field", "Turbo_Boost");
```

That could cause your search to possibly fail.  This has to do with the `Analyzer` you used to index the document splitting or changing the case of "Turbo_Boost" when it was indexed, causing the string comparison at search-time to f

The third, and even more likely, has to do with the `Analyzer` class you're using to index your items, versus the one you're using to search with.  Using the same analyzer is important, because each analyzer uses a different `Tokenizer` that splits the text into searchable terms.

Let me give you some examples using your own `Turbo_Boost` query on how each analyzer will split the text into terms:

> KeywordAnalyzer, WhitespaceAnalyzer -> Field:Turbo_Boost
>
> SimpleAnalyzer, StopAnalyzer -> Field:turbo Field:boost
>
> StandardAnalyzer -> Field:turbo Field:boost

You'll notice some of the `Analyzers` are splitting the term on the underscore character, while `KeywordAnalyzer` keeps it.  It is **extremely** important that you use the same analyzer when you search, because you may not get the same results.  It can also cause issues where *sometimes* the query will find results and other times it won't, all this depending on the query used.

As a side note, if you are using the `StandardAnalyzer`, it's also important that you pass it the same `Version` to the `IndexWriter` and `QueryParser`, because there are differences in how the parsing is done depending on which version of Lucene you expect it to emulate.

My guess your issue is one of those above reasons.

Comment: StandardAnalyzer splits Turbo_Boost.   `string str = new StandardAnalyzer().TokenStream("",new StringReader("Turbo_Boost")).Next().TermText();`

Comment: _WhitespaceAnalyzer_ --> Field:Turbo_Boost     
_StandardAnalyzer_, _StopAnalyzer_, _SimpleAnalyzer_ --> Field:"turbo boost".   

(`Field:turbo Field:boost`) does not equal to (`Field:"turbo boost"`)

Comment: ClassicAnalyzer in Lucene.Net?

Comment: I got lazy and was using Java's analyzers.  Also, I said I was showing how it would split the text into terms; not queries.  You are correct in that is how they would be written as a PhraseQuery, but that was not what I was showing.